The sum of $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+a\right)$
As the title mentioned, I want to have the value of the sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+a\right),
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a positive number, and $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient. The two in the denominator of the Gamma function is difficult to deal with, otherwise it can be written as some kind of hypergeometric function.
Though I want to have a exact result, a tight upper bound is also welcomed.

I guess you could start with using the recursive property of Gamma function: $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$. That would take out the gamma out of the sum and leave you with binomial coefficients and factorials to deal with.

$\Gamma(0)$ is undefined.

$C^k_n$ is your notation for ${n\choose k}$?

@Jan In my exact problem, it is $\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+a\right)$ where $a$ is a positive real number. I simplified it and did not notice this problem, thank you for your reply.

@ Gerry Myerson Yes, exactly. I will edit and mention it.

Hi, even if you star the sum at $k=1$ you have:
$$ n>k \implies \binom{k}{n} = C_n^k = 0$$
$$  \implies  \sum_{k=1}^{n} C_n^k \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right) = C_{n}^{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$$

@Bertrand87 Thank you for your comment. I think I have expressed the binomial coefficients wrong. I have revised it, please check the problem again.

if you call $u_n$ this sum, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u_n}{n!}z^n$ is easy to compute and the result shows that there is no hope for a simpler expression. In the other hand things are not really worse with Gamma(k/2+a)

@LetacGérard Thank you for your comment. I wonder how to do $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{u_n}{n!}z^n$, and what is the relationship between this sum and the sum I want?

I suppose that the result is of the form $$\Gamma (n+1) \left(\alpha_n  \left(\left\lfloor
\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right)+\beta _n
\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor
+1\right)\right)$$ The problem remains : what are the $(\alpha_n,\beta_n)$

@ClaudeLeibovici Hi, nice to see you again. It seems to me that both you and Letac are separating odd and even terms to deal with the 2 in the denominator. But I think the front term should be kind of $\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})$ or $\Gamma(a)$ instead of $\Gamma(n+1)$? I just can't imagine where $\Gamma(n+1)$ turns out.

Go from binomial coefficients to the gamma function.  Have a look at my comment to @Letac Gérard

Ok, that makes sense to me.

If it's of any help, I noticed that your sum can be written in integral form. In particular, $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a-1}\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^ne^{-x}dx$$

$\frac{u_n}{n!}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k!}\Gamma(k/2)\times \frac{1}{(n-k)!}$ implies
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u_n}{n!}z^n=A(z)B(z)$ where
$B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ and
$$A(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Gamma(k/2)\frac{z^k}{k!}=A_0(z)+A_1(z)$$ with
$$A_0(z)=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\Gamma(p)\frac{z^{2p}}{(2p)!},\ \ A_1(z)=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\Gamma(\frac{2p+1}{2})\frac{z^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)!}$$I $$A_1(z)=\sum _{p=0}^{\infty }\frac{(2p-1)(2p-3)\ldots 3.1}{2^p}\Gamma(1/2)\times \frac{z^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)!}$$$$=\sqrt{\pi}\sum _{p=0}^{\infty }\frac{(2p)!}{2^{2p}p!}\times \frac{z^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)!}=\sqrt{\pi}\sum _{p=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^{2p}p!}\times \frac{z^{2p+1}}{2p+1}.$$
Therefore
$A_1'(z)=\sqrt{\pi}e^{z^2/4}.$
For $A_0$ we must use $\int_0^1x^{p-1}(1-x)^{p-1}dx=B(p,p)=\frac{(p-1)!(p-1)!}{(2p-1)!}.$ As a consequence
$$A_0(z)=\sum _{p=1}^{\infty }\frac{(p-1)!}{(2p)!}z^{2p}$$$$=\sum _{p=1}^{\infty }\int_0^1x^{p-1}(1-x)^{p-1}dx\times \frac{z^{2p}}{(p-1)! 2p}$$$$=\sum _{p=0}^{\infty }\int_0^1x^{p}(1-x)^{p}dx\times \frac{z^{2p+2}}{(p)! (2p+2)}.$$
Therefore $$A_0'(z)=z\int_0^1e^{x(1-x)z^2}dx, \ \ A_0(z)=\int_0^1\frac{e^{x(1-x)z^2}-1}{x(1-x)}dx.$$
I cannot do more.

Thank you for your time, hope to see your complete answer.

For what it is worth $$A_0(z)=\frac{1}{2} z^2 ,
_2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{z^2}{4}\right)$$ and, assuming $z>0$, $$A_2(z)=\pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)-\sqrt{\pi
} z$$

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for your supplement. I am new to this area, what is the relationship between this sum and my sum?

Just out of curiosity : may I ask where are you located ? I am in Pau (SW of France- close to the Spanish border and to the Atlantic). I did not manage to find the recursion formulae for the $ (\alpha_n,\beta_n)$ of my comment.

On the globe of Earth, we are not far since I live in the Tarn.

If, by chance, you want to speak, I am in the phone book

Can be written as a sum of 2 terminating hypergeometric series:
$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\Gamma(a+k/2)
=
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}\Gamma(a+k/2)
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)(n+1)_{-k}}\Gamma(a+k/2)
$$
$$
=
\sum_{k\ge 0\ldots}^n \frac{(-)^k(-n)_k}{\Gamma(k+1)}\Gamma(a+k/2)
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-n)_{2k}}{\Gamma(2k+1)}\Gamma(a+k)
- 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(-n)_{2k+1}}{\Gamma(2k+2)}\Gamma(a+1/2+k)
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-n)_{2k}}{\Gamma(2k+1)}\Gamma(a+k)
-
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{\Gamma(2k+1-n)}{\Gamma(-n)\Gamma(2k+2)}\Gamma(a+1/2+k)
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-n)_{2k}}{\Gamma(2k+1)}\Gamma(a+k)
- 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(2k-n)\Gamma(2k-n)}{\Gamma(-n)\Gamma(2k+2)}\Gamma(a+1/2+k)
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-n)_{2k}}{\Gamma(2k+1)}\Gamma(a+k)
- 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(2k-n)(-n)_{2k}}{\Gamma(2k+2)}\Gamma(a+1/2+k)
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-n/2)_k(1/2-n/2)_k 2^{2k}}{(1)_{2k}}\Gamma(a+k)
- 
\Gamma(a+1/2) 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(k-n/2)(-n/2)_k(1/2-n/2)_k2^{2k}}{(2)_{2k}}(a+1/2)_k
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-n/2)_k(1/2-n/2)_k }{(1/2)_k(1)_k}\Gamma(a+k)
- 
\Gamma(a+1/2) 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(k-n/2)(-n/2)_k(1/2-n/2)_k}{(1)_k(3/2)_k}(a+1/2)_k
$$
$$
= 
\Gamma(a)\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{(-n/2)_k(1/2-n/2)_k }{(1/2)_k(1)_k}(a)_k
- 
\Gamma(a+1/2) 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(k-n/2)(-n/2)_k(1/2-n/2)_k}{(1)_k(3/2)_k} (a+1/2)_k
$$
$$
= 
\Gamma(a){}_3F_1(-n/2,1/2-n/2,a; 1/2;1)
+ 
n\Gamma(a+1/2) {}_3F_1(1-n/2,1/2-n/2,a+1/2;3/2;1)
$$
